# Singleton annotation - New singleton created before post-destroy called

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, glassfish-4

I'm using a singleton to use `JODConverter`. The problem is, when a new request is received, a new singleton is created while the old one is destroyed, but the order does not match : the `@PostContruct` method of the new singleton is called before the `@PreDestroy` method of the old one.

This cause a failure, since the server is already running for `JodConverter`.

Here is the code :

```
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.CONTAINER)
@Startup
@Singleton
public class FileConverter {

    private static final String PROPERTIES_FILE = "path/conf.properties";
    private static final String OO_HOME_KEY = "viewers.ooHome";
    private static final String OO_PORT_KEY = "viewers.ooPort";
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(FileConverter.class.getName());

    private OfficeManager officeManager;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            inputStream = FileConverter.class.getResourceAsStream(PROPERTIES_FILE);
            properties.load(inputStream);
            String ooHome = properties.getProperty(OO_HOME_KEY);
            int ooPort = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty(OO_PORT_KEY));
            officeManager = new DefaultOfficeManagerConfiguration()
                    .setOfficeHome(new File(ooHome))
                    .setPortNumber(ooPort)
                    .buildOfficeManager();
            officeManager.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            try{
                if(inputStream!=null){
                    inputStream.close();
                }
            }catch (IOException e){
                LOGGER.log(Level.FINEST, null, e);
            }
        }
    }

    @PreDestroy
    private void close(){
        officeManager.stop();
    }
```

Edit:

I've changed from javax.ejb.Singleton to javax.inject.Singleton and managed the concurrency on my own. Thanks a lot @peeskillet

Comment: I wonder if maybe you are using `@javax.ejb.Singleton` instead of `@javax.inject.Singleton`

Comment: yes i'm using javax.ejb.Singleton ! And yes by switching to javax.inject.Singleton and it's working. But apparently it does not support concurrency which I need in this singleton business logic

Comment: Does this singleton have any business methods? If so, how are you referencing it?